# why i always get "FALSE" when i check the value in database?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to check is the value exists in database but I always get false when I run the code below. can anyone please help me??

```php
$key_in = $key_in_error = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    if (empty(trim($_POST["key_in"]))) {
        $key_in_error = "Please enter job number.";
    }
//    } else {
//        $key_in = trim($_POST["key_in"]);

        $key_in = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$key_in);  // SECURITY!
        $result = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM files WHERE job_no='$key_in'");
        if (mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
            header("location: downloads.php");
        } else {

            echo"Not valid job number!";
        }
    }
```

Comment: what's the value of your echo $key_in?

Comment: @ϻᴇᴛᴀʟ $key_in is the user's input value

Comment: @KrisRoofe I'm not sure what do u mean?

Comment: Did you check your `$result` with [mysqli_error](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) to see if there is any problem with your query?

Comment: Also, did you check your `$result` with [mysqli_num_rows](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) to see if there is any result at all with your query?

Comment: You never assign a new value to `$key_in`. You should un-comment `$key_in = trim($_POST["key_in"]);`.

Comment: @KoalaYeung my query checking with mysqli_error is succeed but still no result with mysqli_num_rows

Comment: @Phil It works! Thank you

Comment: Really appreciate thanks everyone for helping me!

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
$key_in = $key_in_error = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    if (empty(trim($_POST["key_in"]))) {
    $key_in_error = "Please enter job number.";}
//    } else {
//        $key_in = trim($_POST["key_in"]);

        $key_in = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$key_in);  // SECURITY!
        $result = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM files WHERE job_no='$key_in'");
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result)>0) {
            header("location: downloads.php");
        } else {

            echo"Not valid job number!";
        }
    }
```

Comment: This does not work for me..The result is still the same.

Comment: Thanks @Mukesh Yadav I've solved the problem by uncommenting the two lines and then removing the security line.